# How can I remove and recreate an existing symbolic link in one single command?

Tags: linux, symlink

I have a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) for my live server called `current` and I have releases in the `releases` directory, i.e., `current -> releases/2012-05-08_15-13`

If I want to update the symbolic link of my `current` directory, I have to `unlink`/`rm` it and re `ln -s` it.

How can I remove the symbolic link and update it to the latest release in one step?

Comment: you mean that you want **current** to point something new?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The form of ln is

```
ln -sf sourcefile targetlink
```

Try

```
ln -sf releases/2012-05-08_15-13 current
```

to remove the current and create the new link.

Comment: try ln -sfn sourcefile targetlink or it won't work. At least on Linux.

Comment: @Matt Why don't you post your comment as an answer and get credit for having the only answer with the right info?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in a single command, do as @hughw suggests and run `ln -sf`.

If you want to replace the symlink atomically (ie. so that there's no point in time where the symlink doesn't exist) create a new symlink, then `mv` it over the old one.

Comment: you need the n switch too, ln -sfn

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by ToddR, here is the only answer that actually works on maybe most flavours of Linux—definitely Ubuntu—which uses *[ln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix))* from the [coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) package).  Let me prove it to you.

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir -p releases/dirA
$ mkdir -p releases/dirB
$ ln -s releases/dirA
$ ls -l dirA
lrwxrwxrwx 1 matthewh matthewh 13 Apr  7 09:58 dirA -> releases/dirA
$ ln -sf releases/dirB
$ rm dirA
$ ln -s releases/dirA current
$ ln -sf releases/dirB current
$ ls -l current
lrwxrwxrwx 1 matthewh matthewh 13 Apr  7 09:59 current -> releases/dirA  <--- DOESN'T WORK!
$ ln -sfn releases/dirB current <--- WORKS!
$ ls -l current
lrwxrwxrwx 1 matthewh matthewh 13 Apr  7 09:59 current -> releases/dirB
```

So the correct method on Linux is:

```
ln -sfn source target
```

> -n, --no-dereference
> treat LINK_NAME as a normal file if it is a symbolic link to a directory

This is essential, if you do not use -n switch you will end up with a symlink inside source directory named "target".

In my examples,

```
$ ls -l releases/dirA/

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 matthewh matthewh 13 Apr  7 10:03 dirB -> releases/dirB
```

Answer (score 1):

A correct answer:

```
ln -s new current_tmp && mv -Tf current_tmp current
```

Move is an atomic operation.

Don't use 'ln -snf'. [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) 'ln -snf' shows two system calls, [unlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlink_(Unix)) + [symlink](https://linux.die.net/man/2/symlink).

Answer (score 0):

This example clears the use of the *-sfn* switch:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root    root         4096 Aug 25 18:24 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 25 root    root         4096 Aug 19 10:32 ..
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 wildfly wildfly        25 Aug 25 18:15 wildfly -> /opt/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/
drwxr-xr-x. 10 wildfly wildfly      4096 Aug 25 18:28 wildfly-8.2.0.Final
```

---

```
                link to            link
                  |                 |
sudo ln -sfn wildfly-8.2.0.Final /opt/wildfly
ls -la
```

Output:

```
total 115540
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root    root         4096 Aug 25 18:34 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 25 root    root         4096 Aug 19 10:32 ..
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root    root           19 Aug 25 18:34 wildfly -> wildfly-8.2.0.Final
drwxr-xr-x. 10 wildfly wildfly      4096 Aug 25 18:28 wildfly-8.2.0.Final
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"clears the use"*? Can you elaborate? Or perhaps rephrase?